# setTitleTextAttributes on UIBarButtonItem appearance proxy for different styles

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I would like to style my UIBarButtonItems with a custom font. I am using the appearance proxy on UIBarButtonItem's titleTextAttributes to accomplish this successfully. However, I would like to set different font styles for different UIBarButtonItem styles (i.e. Medium for style Bordered, Bold for style Done).

Here is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
  //Navigation Items


NSDictionary *normalAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIFont myCustomLabelWithSize:18.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
                                    nil
                                    ];
  [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:normalAttributes
                                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

What would be great is if there was a setTitleTextAttribues:forState:style...

How can I accomplish this, preferable while still using the appearance proxy?